# Account Hierarchy Salesforce Accounts - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tree, salesforce

I am working on a report that uses Salesforce Datawarehouse. Essentially, given a particular account, I need to find the hierarchy just for that. This could be at any level down but it HAS to get ALL the NODES.

The following is what I have:

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name) as 
(
   SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name
   FROM accounts
   WHERE (parentid IS NULL 
   AND recordtypeid NOT IN ('012G0000001NLJSIA4', '012G0000001NLKGIA4'))

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1, c2.name
   FROM accounts c2 
     INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
     AND recordtypeid NOT IN ('012G0000001NLJSIA4', '012G0000001NLKGIA4')
)
SELECT *
FROM tree
```

What I really should be able to do is provide an account parameter, whose details I am looking for and have it only return the hierarchy for that.

Any Help? I have been struggling this with for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the datatype of your account ID's are; however, I stayed safe and chose INT. All you need to do is use a parameter for the anchor portion of the CTE, and that will be defined as level 0 with the recursive portion returning all of the children of the given parent. Why don't you try the following:

```
Declare @id INT = 1234;

WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name) as 
(
   SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name
   FROM accounts
   WHERE id = @id
   AND recordtypeid NOT IN ('012G0000001NLJSIA4', '012G0000001NLKGIA4')

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1, c2.name
   FROM accounts c2 
     INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
     AND recordtypeid NOT IN ('012G0000001NLJSIA4', '012G0000001NLKGIA4')
)
SELECT *
FROM tree
```

Comment: Hmm this does not entirely Work. It only seems to give me the Children node going forward and down the list. But it should get all the nodes above that too and essentially all of its parents as well.

Comment: That does seem to be what you asked for. If you need going up as well you would need a second CTE (which can join to "tree") and start at a certain point, namely the parameter, and simply find its parent. The only fun you're going to have with this is getting the correct level for each one since you'd be starting with the child in question who is somewhere in the middle of the hierarchy.