# Generate hierarchical path (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, hierarchical-data, sql-server-2019

I have a `classstructure` table:

```
create table classstructure (classstructureid int, classificationid varchar(25), parent int);

insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1001, 'FLEET', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1002, 'LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1004, 'MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1022, 'ACTIVETRANSPORTATION', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1023, 'FACILITYWALKWAY', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1024, 'TRAIL', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1085, 'SIDEWALK', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1091, 'SDWRAMP', 1085);


CLASSSTRUCTUREID CLASSIFICATIONID              PARENT
---------------- ------------------------- ----------
            1001 FLEET                               
            1002 LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE                1001
            1004 MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE               1001

            1022 ACTIVETRANSPORTATION                
            1023 FACILITYWALKWAY                 1022
            1024 TRAIL                           1022
            1085 SIDEWALK                        1022
            1091 SDWRAMP                         1085
```

I want to create a query that will collapse the records down to hierarchy paths:

```
HIERARCHYPATH
---------------------------
FLEET
FLEET \ LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE
FLEET \ MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE 

ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ FACILITYWALKWAY
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ TRAIL
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK \ SDWRAMP
```

**How can I do this with SQL?**

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** This can be accomplished using a recursive CTE. Here's another answer on StackOverflow in which I answered this question: [Account Hierarchy Salesforce Accounts - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827864/account-hierarchy-salesforce-accounts-sql-server/44828057#44828057)

**Longer description:** Your data structure is a classic way in which hierarchical data is stored in a database. A recursive CTE will start at a certain point and loop recursively until the condition is no longer true (all children were found), hence the name; recursive. There are a few disclaimers, such as the limit of recursions (how many rounds it does),though that can be mitigated if needs be.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a standard recursive CTE.  CTE's are great for small to medium  hierarchies, however, if your hierarchy is LARGE, there other techniques using temp tables which are more performant.

Note: the column `HierID` is optional.  It just offers a proper sequence

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2671d150db2a7220bd1e892e58ffdcd5)**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select [CLASSSTRUCTUREID]
            ,[Parent] 
            ,[CLASSIFICATIONID]
            ,[HIERARCHYPATH] = convert(varchar(500),[CLASSIFICATIONID])
            ,[HierID]        = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',[CLASSSTRUCTUREID],'/'))
      From   classstructure 
      Where  [Parent] is null
      Union  All
      Select [CLASSSTRUCTUREID]  = r.[CLASSSTRUCTUREID]
            ,[Parent]            = r.[Parent] 
            ,[CLASSIFICATIONID]  = r.[CLASSIFICATIONID]
            ,[HIERARCHYPATH]     = convert(varchar(500),concat(p.[HIERARCHYPATH],' \ ',r.[CLASSIFICATIONID]))
            ,[HierID]            = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.[CLASSSTRUCTUREID],'/'))
      From   classstructure  r
      Join   cteP p on r.[Parent]  = p.[CLASSSTRUCTUREID])
Select [CLASSSTRUCTUREID]
      ,[Parent]
      ,[CLASSIFICATIONID]
      ,[HIERARCHYPATH]
 From cteP A
 Order by [HierID]
```

**Results**

[image]

Personally, I like to include the hierarchy LEVEL in the final results.  In the final SELECT, you could include:

```
...
[Level]   = HierID.GetLevel()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
with CTE_Rec as
(
    select 
        cast(classificationid as varchar(500)) classificationid, 
        classstructureid 
    from classstructure 
    where parent is null
    
    union All
    
    Select 
        cast(b.classificationid+' \ '+a.classificationid as varchar(500)),
        a.classstructureid
    from classstructure a 
    inner join CTE_REC b on b.classstructureid = a.parent 
) 
Select 
    classificationid 
from CTE_Rec
order by classificationid
```